# How to save in django using expression as keyword

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to create an entry in a single column of the model/table by iterating an array of objects. The array of objects is something like this:

```
arr = [
       { "field_name" : "email", "field_value" : "abc@abc.com" },
       { "field_name" : "name", "field_value" : "Abc Xyz" },
       { "field_name" : "gender", "field_value" : "M" }
      ]
```

I want the data to be saved like this:

```
| **email**         | **name**      | **gender** |
| abc@abc.com   | Abc Xyz   | M      |
```

Suppose if I have a model named "model_name", then the code which I have written is like this:

```
modelObject = model_name()

for data in arr:
     modelObject( data['field_name'] = data['field_value'] )

modelObject.save()
```

I want to save this data in a single-go as the data corresponds to a single column. But the code which I have written is giving "keyword can't be an expression" Error at line:

```
modelObject( data['field_name'] = data['field_value'] )
```

Can somebody help me in figuring a way out of this?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data in a dictionary and pass them to the model class using *unpacking*:

```
for data in arr:
    obj = modelObject(**{data['field_name']: data['field_value']})
    obj.save()
```

Remember to add a reference to the newly created object and save each object in the `for` loop using the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `arr` to dict of field names and values and then unpack them:

```
obj = modelObject(**{data['field_name']: data['field_value'] for data in arr})
obj.save()
```